# Newbie Question: Connect K8s Cluster to a External MySQL DB With Whitelist

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I'm trying to connect a kubernetes deployment with a mysql database hosted in AWS. We need to use the whitelist protection of the AWS instance but i'm not able to connect the node instance (the kubernetes deployment) to the mysql database. I have tried adding the ip address of the pod, the nginx-ingress controller external ip address and the nodes ip addresses and nothing.

It's there an specific ip address that i can use to go through the whitelist on the db??

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

is your kubernetes deployment running on premises ? could you please make sure that there is no egress policies setup in your namespace which is blocking the access to RDS mysql instance in AWS.

Comment: it's not, we have it on a google cloud gke instance, but im gonna check any egress policies

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).